# Resolving inside OWIN callback delegates

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

What is the correct way for resolving objects inside OWIN callback delegates?

Assuming `AutofacConfig.AutofacContainer` is an `IContainer` and that `IServiceManager` has been registered as `InstancePerRequest`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnResponseSignIn = cookieSignInCtx =>
        {
            // this?
            using (var scope = AutofacConfig.AutofacContainer.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
            {
                var serviceManager = scope.Resolve<IServiceManager>();
            }

            // or this?
            var serviceManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IServiceManager>();

            // or something else?
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than solving the issue for you this is how we resolved the **IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** provider.  Similar (if not the same) idea ;).

```
const string publicClientId = "self";
var prod = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(new NamedParameter("publicClientId", publicClientId));

var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = prod,
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

The provider was registered like this:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
{
    DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("MyWebAPI")
});
```